# unity2d scaling canvas to fit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, canvas, resolution

I've been trying to create a basic menu for my android game. I originally created it using a world space canvas, which worked fine. However, I am now changing it so my canvas fits to any android screen. I have been messing around with different resolutions for the canvas to try to get it to fit, but it never properly fits, and I am not sure what I have not set up properly. Here is an example, with a 480x800 canvas resolution, and matching the resolution for the game window. Is there anything I am obviously doing wrong in the way i've set out my canvas that is stopping it scale properly?

[image: game]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there anything I am obviously doing wrong in the way i've set out my canvas that is stopping it scale properly?

Comment: Edit your question to include this. The answer is you can move your relevant UI icons INTO the space as defined by the outline in the editor. Otherwise set your render move to camera and set it to your main camera. Ensure all your anchors are set correctly, to account for different resolution sizes.

Comment: I have tried readjusting the UI elements for different resolutions, however, when I correctly sort them for the game window, they will still be slightly misaligned on the phone. I believe all anchors are correct.

Comment: Unity's UI system is a nightmare. @cmprogram it doesn't behave in any manner familiar to anyone that's ever used any other form of UI creation. It's that confusing... I know because I'm...

Comment: You know how anchors behaviour works? if not I recommend you to read about the subject (https://forum.unity.com/threads/i-do-not-really-understand-how-the-anchor-system-works.263844/)

Comment: @Confused The Unity UI system, specifically the improvements with the canvas system is completely fine. It's working exactly as intended in this image. It shows you the viewport, some elements are off the screen, so they appear off the screen. No problem. As mentioned, if you set the Render Mode to Camera, and set it to Main Camera, you can then position your elements appropriately, and format the anchors to they know which elements of the screen they can take up. By reading the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html), you will quickly be able to solve any issues.

Comment: @cmprogram "You're holding it wrong" is nowhere near sufficient to explain away the travesty of contrivances and arbitrary nonsense that is the 'design' of the UI system in Unity, which was a workaround brought in-house. I have read its sad documentation and used some of its modes. It is terrible. Possibly the worst UI system ever created and foisted into first place in a game engine. Makes Scale Form look like pure, unadulterated, elegant genius.

Comment: Sorry, fixed this last night, I was simply using an odd resolution for my phone! Not sure how to mark as answered without anyone replying with an answer!